# legend for selected plot objects in MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure

For a MATLAB figure, I have something like:

```
figure; hold on;
line ( [1 2], [3 4] );
line ( [5 6], [7 8] );

plot(x1,y1,'r.');
plot(x2,y2,'b.');
```

where x1,y1,x2,y2 are all vectors.

How can I add `legend` for only the last two plots, not for the two lines?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2204V1/index.html?solution=1-2204V1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to get the handles for the last two plots and tell `legend` to plot only for those two. For example:

```
h1 = plot(x1,y1,'r.');
h2 = plot(x2,y2,'b.');
legend([h1,h2],'red','blue')
```