# Is is possible to name a plot and attain a legend in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, legend

I have several plots in a MATLAB code. But handling the legend colors each time is painful. Is there a way to name plots such as plot1=... and then using this name attaina  color to a corresponding legend?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243128/legend-for-selected-plot-objects-in-matlab-figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
plot1 = plot(x,y);
legend(plot1, 'series 1', 'series 2');
```

`plot1` is called the [figure handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html)